# Continue executing a dom command

Tags: javascript

I use this dom command in some testing pages:

```
document.querySelector('div#summary-item div.description').innerHTML || ""
```

But in some pages when the first part does not exist I don't receive the second "" but I receive this error and my programm stops

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null(…)
```

Is there any simple way to receive the "" without the need to use the typeof in an if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `typeof` but you do need an `if` statement or some other flow control.

```
var el = document.querySelector('div#summary-item div.description');
var data = "";
if (el)
  data = el.innerHTML;
```

Or here it is using the conditional operator:

```
var el = document.querySelector('div#summary-item div.description');
var data = el ? el.innerHTML : "";
```

---

Technically, you could get away without using a flow control statement or expression by using an object that has a `.innerHTML` property.

```
var data = (document.querySelector('div#summary-item div.description') || {innerHTML:""}).innerHTML;
```

But I think that's ugly. `if` statements are part of the language. Not sure why you'd want to avoid it.

---

Of course, you could always use a function that abstracts it away if it really bothers you.

```
function htmlFromElem(selector) {
    var el = document.querySelector(selector);
    return el ? el.innerHTML : "";
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var data = htmlFromElem('div#summary-item div.description')
```